# Firebase Data-structure best ways

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, nosql

I am tying to active this Data-structure for my application. I am little bid confuse the structure and rule. What I did still now -

[image]

Can any one suggest me is it the best way?

Comment: There is no single best way to model data in a NoSQL database. It all depends on how your app uses the data. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). But definitely also read [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), which shows the recommended way to store lists of data.

Comment: Thank you very much the second link was really helpful to understand.